# python-social-auth "facebook Authentication process canceled"

Tags: python, django, facebook, oauth, python-social-auth

I read several web pages and wrote following these codes. But when I tried to pass the authorization with facebook, this appeared on my terminal.

> "GET /login/facebook/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 Authentication process
>   canceled

settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '4hqhqj51j13j1.....'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

# when we develop in testcase
# DEBUG = True
# ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# when we release our site
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.core.context_processors.debug',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'django.core.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db/django.sqlite3'),
    },
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)


SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'Your facebook Key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'Your facebook Secret'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_NAMESPACE = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'local': 'ja_JP',
    'fields': 'id, name, email, are_range',
    }
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = 'Your Twitter Key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = 'Your Twitter Secret'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'jp-JP'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'

DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'static'),
)


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

#MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get(“OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR’, ”)
#MEDIA_URL = ‘/media/’
```

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def login(request):
    # context = RequestContext(request, {
    #     'request': request, 'user': request.user})
    # return render_to_response('login.html', context_instance=context)
    return render(request, 'myapp/login/login.html')


@login_required(login_url='/')
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('/myapp/login/home.html')


def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.views import login
from myapp.views import home
from myapp.views import logout


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^home/$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
] # + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

myapp/login.html

```
<html>
<body>
{% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
    <a>Hello, {{ user.get_full_name }}!</a>
    <br>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with Facebook</a>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

What did I miss?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I deleted those, I could solve. Gee, It took so much time......(｀ε´)ぶーぶー

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_NAMESPACE = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'local': 'ja_JP',
    'fields': 'id, name, email, are_range',
    }
```